# How to checkout a user selected branch with Jenkins pipelines

Tags: jenkins

I would like to create a Jenkins pipeline job that allows users to input their branch choice and then proceed with the build from there.

For now it seems the default `git` object does not allow such feature. I tried to create a input selection manually but executing git command that fetches an array of branches manually seems to be forbidden in pipeline scripts.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this currently?